# Teradata REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE Input Parameter

Tags: function, teradata

I'd like to be able to define an input parameter in a CTE and then use it within a REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE function, like so:

```
WITH PARAMS (INPUT_PARAMS) AS
(SELECT
    '?InputParams' AS INPUT_PARAMS
)
SELECT
    TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
FROM
    TABLE (REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, PARAMS.INPUT_PARAMS, '\|', 'i')
        RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS TEST_TABLE
    CROSS JOIN PARAMS
```

However this yields the following error:

> SELECT Failed.  [3706] Syntax error: Joined table is not supported in
>   conjuction with table operators or table function invoked with
>   variable input argument.

Putting the parameter right in the function works, as below:

```
SELECT
    TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
FROM
    TABLE (REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, '?InputParams', '\|', 'i') --
        RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS TEST_TABLE
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do something more like the first example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function doesn't allow JOIN-syntax, but you can do old-style joins:

```
WITH PARAMS (INPUT_PARAMS) AS
(SELECT
    '?InputParams' AS INPUT_PARAMS
)
SELECT
    TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
FROM
    TABLE (REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, PARAMS.INPUT_PARAMS, '\|', 'i')
        RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS TEST_TABLE
    ,PARAMS
```

In fact you don't need the join at all:

```
WITH PARAMS (INPUT_PARAMS) AS
(SELECT
    '?InputParams' AS INPUT_PARAMS
)
SELECT
    TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
FROM
    TABLE (REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, PARAMS.INPUT_PARAMS, '\|', 'i')
        RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS TEST_TABLE
```

And as you don't use a regular expression you might also switch to `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE`:

```
WITH PARAMS (INPUT_PARAMS) AS
(SELECT
    '?InputParams' AS INPUT_PARAMS
)
SELECT
    TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
FROM
    TABLE (StrTok_Split_To_Table(1, PARAMS.INPUT_PARAMS, '\|')
        RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET Unicode)) AS TEST_TABLE
```

Comment: Answer # 3 is great. I thought I should be switching to STROK, but that meant trying to use the TD documentation so I gave up after a while :). The most helpful and unexpected part is that "In fact you don't need the Join at all." This means I can put the unjoined split in my CTEs and then join the WITH to other tables in my real code. One question: Why isn't a join necessary? It seems like since I'm referring to PARAMS inside the TABLE function that it would need to be joined to. Not that I'm complaining ... Thanks again!

Comment: @DougGlancy: Don't ask me why the syntax is like this (the documentation is really quite bad). It's a kind of correlated join, imho similar to Standard SQL's *Lateral Join*.

Comment: Well, I'm just glad it works, and that we have you to supplement the documentation. Thanks again Dieter.