# Teradata - Two Joins to a CTE StrTok_Split_To_Table function - Error 3807

Tags: teradata, common-table-expression

This question is related to the excellent answer to this question: [Teradata REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE Input Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39709105/293078). Below is the simplest example I can create.

I have a TERADATA query with two CTEs (WITH clauses). The first CTE contains a STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE function that refers to the second CTE which collects a parameter from the user. The body of the query has a SELECT statement that references the first CTE and gets a column of split parameters. This works great:

```
WITH 
    SPLIT_PARAMS(PARAM) AS
    (SELECT
        TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
    FROM
        TABLE (StrTok_Split_To_Table(1, PARAMS.INPUT_PARAMS, '|')
            RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET Unicode)) AS TEST_TABLE)
    ,

    PARAMS (INPUT_PARAMS) AS
    (SELECT
        '?InputParams' AS INPUT_PARAMS
    )

SELECT 
    SPLIT_PARAMS.PARAMS
FROM SPLIT_PARAMS
```

However, I want to be able to refer to the SPLIT_PARAMS CTE more than once. When I do that I get a `[3807] object 'PARAMS' does not exist` error:

```
WITH 
    SPLIT_PARAMS(PARAM) AS
    (SELECT
        TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
    FROM
        TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, PARAMS.INPUT_PARAMS, '|')
            RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS TEST_TABLE)
    ,

    PARAMS (INPUT_PARAMS) AS
    (SELECT
        '?InputParams' AS INPUT_PARAMS
    )

SELECT 
    SP1.PARAM,
    SP2.PARAM
FROM SPLIT_PARAMS SP1
    CROSS JOIN SPLIT_PARAMS SP2
```

I've tried a bunch of things, like putting two SPLIT_PARAMS subqueries in the main query and using the old-style JOINs referred to in the answer to the previous question. However, any attempt to JOIN to the SPLIT_PARAMS CTE more than once yields this error. (My actual setup is three CTEs deep, but the result is the same - "PARAMS does not exist."

Comment: Multiple CTEs in Teradata are a huge pain.  You have to define them in reverse order.  I tend to just use volatile tables.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I use multiple CTEs quite a bit and have gotten used to the reverse order constraint. The issue here has to do with multiple joins to the CTE containing the `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` function. Regarding volatile tables, my co-workers tell me they don't work in Crystal Reports/BOXI, which is the front end we use to publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may, but doesn't necessarily answer your question, there is really no need for your second CTE here: Simply pushing the input parameter up into the strtok_Split_to_table function will allow you to hit the Split_Params cte more than once:

```
WITH SPLIT_PARAMS(PARAM) AS
(
    SELECT
        TEST_TABLE.SPLIT_PARAMS
    FROM
        TABLE
        (
            StrTok_Split_To_Table(1, '?InputParams', '|')
            RETURNS (outkey INTEGER, TOKENNUM INTEGER, SPLIT_PARAMS VARCHAR(8192) CHARACTER SET Unicode)
        ) AS TEST_TABLE
)
SELECT 
    SP1.PARAM,
    SP2.PARAM
FROM SPLIT_PARAMS SP1
    CROSS JOIN SPLIT_PARAMS SP2
```

Comment: This was my starting point when I was first trying to figure out how to get the parameter out of the function: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39709105/293078. Interestingly, I'd since lost sight of that as an option. It beats the only other thing I've come up with, which is doubling (tripling...) each set of CTEs. Definitely deserves an upvote!

Comment: The other option would be to not use a CTE, but rather stick that Split_Params in your main query as a subquery, just multiple times, since CTE's aren't working for you here.

Comment: Actually, your answer above works fine. The only issue it doesn't solve is just an aesthetic one, wanting all my parameters (there are others) in one CTE. I'm going to go ahead and accept it. Thanks again.